# "//TODO implement a complete class header"

Tags: c#, header

"//TODO implement a complete class header" working on my final project for my C# class and that is one of the TODO's for the project. I'm not totally sure what it means.

The top of the program that contains that looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

//TODO implement a complete class header

namespace Payroll
{


 [Serializable]


    public abstract class Employee:IPayable
    {
        #region "Variable Declarations"

        //create an enumeration that keeps track of the type
        public enum Type
        {
            Hourly = 1,
            Salary = 2,
            Contract = 3,
            None = 4
        };
```

Comment: show us a few more lines of code, about 5 more please, or 1 at the very least. Or is that all you have?

Comment: Yeah, there's kind of no such thing in C#. Also, the location of the TODO (outside the namespace) is odd. Maybe your instructor means for you to add XML comments to the class (which you can do easily by typing `///` above the class definition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Specify information so that another developer knows what the class does/contains.

You can find out more information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2d6dt3kf.aspx) about `<summary>` tags.

[Recommended Tags for Documentation Comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ast78ax.aspx)

You can also use some software called [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx).

> GhostDoc is a Visual Studio extension
>   that automatically generates XML
>   documentation comments for methods and
>   properties based on their type,
>   parameters, name, and other contextual
>   information.

Answer (score 2):

He or she was probably referring to an [XML documentation comment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx) they didn't have to time to write yet.

Answer (score 2):

Probably just referring to adding a documentation header to the class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx